# Vectorized version of the following loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

What I need to do is, given a vector of labels (numbers 1 through k), construct a matrix `Y` such that each column is a Boolean vector representing whether or not each the label in `Y` matches the index of that column.

For example, if `labels = [1 2 3 4]` then `Y` would be:

```
[ [ 1  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  0  0]
  [ 0  0  1  0]
  [ 0  0  0  1] ]
```

So far my code is this:

```
num_classes = 10;
num_samples = 100;

labels = randi(num_classes, [num_samples, 1]);   % Example
Y = zeros([num_samples, num_classes]);

for k = 1:num_classes
    Y(:, k) = (y == k);
end
```

This kinda works but it can be very slow when `num_classes` or `num_samples` is very large. Is there any way to vectorize this?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Matlab version 2015a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
num_classes = 10;
num_samples = 100;
labels = randi(num_classes, [num_samples, 1]);   % Example

Y = bsxfun(@eq, labels, 1:num_classes);
```

Or, if you have 2016b (or Octave) you can do it using implicit broadcasting

```
Y = labels == 1:num_classes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the neural network toolbox you could use [ind2vec](http://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/ind2vec.html):

```
Y = full(ind2vec(labels, num_classes))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. Let's define some example data:

```
num_classes = 5;
num_samples = 10;
labels = [3 5 3 5 3 2 4 4 4 2];
```

Then

```
Y = full(sparse(1:num_samples, labels, 1, num_samples, num_classes));
```

gives the desired result

```
Y =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0
```